# How to isolate a row that contains a value unlike other values in that column in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query in SSMS 2016 that will isolate the value(s) for a group that are unlike the other values within a column. I can explain better with an example:

Each piece of equipment in our fleet has an hour meter reading that gets recorded from a handheld device. Sometimes people in the field enter in a typo meter reading which skews our hourly readings.

So a unit's meter history may look like this:

```
10/1/2019: 2000    
10/2/2019: 2208    
10/4/2019: 2208    
10/7/2019: 2212    
10/8/2019: 2    
10/8/2019: 2225   
...etc.
```

It's obvious that the "2" is a bad record because an hour meter can never decrease.  edit: Sometimes the opposite extreme may occur, where they enter a reading like "22155" and then I would need the query to adapt to find values that are too high and isolate those as well.  This data is stored in a meter history table where there is a single row for each meter reading. I am tasked with creating some type of procedure that will automatically isolate the bad data and delete those rows from the table. How can I write a query that understands the context of the meter history and knows that the 2 is bad?

Any tips welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to get rid of "decreases":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(col2) over (order by col1) as prev_col2
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col2 < col2;
```

I would not advise "automatically deleting" such records.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What if the typo is the opposite, i.e. someone enters 22155 and then the number is too high and needs removed? We see both scenarios often.

Comment: hi Nekaly, in that case you may find value in a query similar to the one I provided. You may also want to consider what constitutes an error. Will the length always be 4? If so, anything that isn't 4 in length should be found. You need to make this determination before coding your resolution.

Comment: @nekalycam . . . This answers the question that you *asked*.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically deleting data is risky, so I'm not certain I'd recommend unleashing that without some serious thought, but here's my idea based on your sample data showing that it's usually a pretty consistent number.

```
DECLARE @Median numeric(22,0);
;with CTE as
(
select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.value) as "rn" from t
)
select @Median = cte.value
where cte.rn = (select (SUM( MAX(RN) + MIN(RN)) / 2 from cte); -- floors if dividing an odd number
select * from dataReadings where reading_value < (0.8 * @median) OR reading_value > (1.2 * @median);
```

The goal of this is to give you a +/- 20% range of the median value, which shouldn't be as skewed by mistakes as an average would be. Again, this assumes that your values should fall into an acceptable range.

If this is meant to be an always-increasing reading and you shouldn't ever encounter lower values, Gordon's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would think to look at the variation of each reading from the mean reading value.  (I picked up the `lag()` check from @Gordon Linoff's reply too.)  For example:

```
create table #test (the_date date, reading int)
insert #test (the_date, reading) values ('10/1/2019', 2000)
                                      , ('10/2/2019', 2208)
                                      , ('10/4/2019', 2208)
                                      , ('10/7/2019', 2212)
                                      , ('10/8/2019', 2)
                                      , ('10/8/2019', 2225)
                                      , ('10/8/2019', 2224)
                                      , ('10/9/2019', 22155)

declare @avg int, @stdev float
select @avg = avg(reading)
     , @stdev = stdev(reading) * 0.5
  from #test

select t.*
     , case when reading < @avg - @stdev then 'SUSPICIOUS - too low'
            when reading > @avg + @stdev then 'SUSPICIOUS - too high'
            when reading < prev_reading then 'SUSPICIOUS - decrease'
       end Comment
from (select t.*, lag(reading) over (order by the_date) as prev_reading
      from #test t
     ) t
```

Which results in:

```
the_date    reading prev_reading    Comment
2019-10-01  2000    NULL    NULL    
2019-10-02  2208    2000    NULL    
2019-10-04  2208    2208    NULL    
2019-10-07  2212    2208    NULL    
2019-10-08  2   2212    SUSPICIOUS - too low    
2019-10-08  2225    2   NULL    
2019-10-08  2224    2225    SUSPICIOUS - decrease   
2019-10-09  22155   2224    SUSPICIOUS - too high
```